# How are the discriminant of a single variable quadratic equation and that of a binary quadratic form related?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

**How are the discriminant in a single variable quadratic equation and the binary quadratic form over the unit circle related?**

I will point out that the discriminant in the quadratic formula has the opposite sign from the used in the following.

This is a screen scrape from my notes based on [Edwards](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486683362.html) showing the determination of the Lagrange multipliers for general binary quadratic form.
[image]

The symbol $\mathcal{J}$ represents a rotation by $\pi/2$ and the expression where it appears is a standard dot product.

If the discriminant is $ac-b^2\ne0$ is positive then both extremal values have the same sign.  Otherwise they have different signs.

This is the graph for a case of a negative discriminant.
[image]

In a quadratic equation in one variable, the discriminant tells us whether we have two real solutions, a single solution or only imaginary solutions.  It seems to me, these two situations must be closely related.

The discriminate of the general quadratic equation is invariant under orthogonal transformations.  It can also be used to eliminate the cross $xy$ term in the case of two variables.

### Addendum:

If someone takes the time to present this in proper mathematical statements, I'll be happy to accept the answer.  The connection is "obvious".  Imagine rotating a cutting plane containing the $z$ axis.  At each angle the intersection between the graph of the quadratic surface and the cutting plane will be a (possibly degenerate) parabola.  If these parabolae all lie entirely above or below the $x\times{y}$ plane, then the corresponding quadratic formulae have no real solutions.  This is the same thing as saying the graph lies entirely above or entirely below the $x\times{y}$ plane.

Comment: “Both” extrema? There are four.

Comment: What do you know about eigenvectors and eigenvalues or the principal axis theorem? The basic connection here is that the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to its determinant, which for a quadratic form is a multiple of its discriminant, and that the extrema of a quadratic form on the unit sphere occur along its principal axes, which are its eigenvectors.

Comment: @amd I really am asking about the connection, if there is one, between the discriminant in the quadratic formula, and the discriminant in the quadratic form.  What you are describing is discussed by Edwards in great detail.  My notes were intended to emphasize that connection.

Comment: If someone takes the time to present this in proper mathematical statements, I'll be happy to accept the answer.  The connection is "obvious".  Imagine rotating a cutting plane containing the $z$ axis.  At each angle the intersection between the graph of the quadratic surface and the cutting plane will be a (possibly degenerate) parabola.  If these parabolae all lie entirely above or below the $x\times{y}$ plane, then the corresponding quadratic formulae have no real solutions.  This is the same thing as saying the graph lies entirely above or entirely below the $x\times{y}$ plane.